# Prove that $AB-BA = I$ has no solution in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ without using matrix trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The title is self-explanatory. Prove that $AB-BA = I$ has no solution in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ without using matrix trace. A,B are both from $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ and $AB$ is matrix multiplication. 
I am aware that these matrices' traces coincide and hence $tr(AB-BA) = 0$, while $tr(I) = n$ but are there other ways to solve this?

Comment: You can show by induction that $A^nB-BA^n=nA^{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$, and then use the minimal polynomial $M$ of $A$: Show that $M^{\prime}(A)=0$.

Comment: You need to use *something* special to characteristic 0, as the result is not true for e.g. $M_2(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$. The reason the trace proof doesn't work here is that $Tr(I_2)=0$.

Comment: That's a cute proof, @Kelenner. You should fill in the details and post it as an answer.

Comment: @Kelenner, nice idea. you can extend the identity to any poly $p$ so that $p(A)B - Bp(A) = p^\prime (A).$ it will be nice to write it as an answer as suggested by Mike Miller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We prove by induction that we have $A^nB-BA^n=nA^{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. (For $n=0$, we get $B-B=0$)For $n=1$ this is clear. Suppose that we have the result for $0\leq k\leq n$. By multipling by $A$ we get $A^{n+1}B-ABA^n=nA^n$ and $A^nBA-BA^{n+1}=nA^n$. Hence adding the two, we get
$$A^{n+1}B-BA^{n+1}+A(A^{n-1}B-BA^{n-1})A=2nA^n$$
and we finish easily.

Now Let $M(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $A$, of degree $d\geq 1$. We get immediately that
$$M(A)B-BM(A)=M^{\prime}(A)=0$$
But this is a contradiction with the definition of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: As a note, the reason this doesn't work in characteristics other than 0 is that $M'(A)$ doesn't have to be nonzero; for instance, in characteristic 2, take $M(A)=A^2-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way, albeit it involves traces at some level.

Let $\phi:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R) \to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ be given by $\phi(A) = AB-BA$. Using the inner product induced by the Frobenius norm, we have $\phi^T(X)= X B^T -B^T X$, and clearly $I \in \ker \phi^T$.
Since $\ker \phi^T = ({\cal R} \phi)^\bot$, we cannot have $I \in {\cal R} \phi$.